# Data from model not passing to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some code that is functioning oddly and was wondering if anyone else hase come across this issue.

I have a view model that collects data from a database via a stored procedure and a vb object (no I do not know vb this is legacy)

When I execute the program the data is collected as expected via the controller.  When I debug it I can see all of my parameters populating with information.  However when it comes to the view it says that the parameters are null.  I have included my code

Models:

```
    public class PersonIncomeViewModel
{
    public string IncomeTypeDesc { get; set; }
    public string IncomeDesc { get; set; }
    public string Income { get; set; }
}

public class PersonIncomeListViewModel
{
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public List<PersonIncomeListItem> Incomes { get; set; }

    public PersonIncomeListViewModel()
    {
        Incomes = new List<PersonIncomeListItem>();
    }
}

    public class PersonLookupViewModel : Queue.QueueViewModel
{
    public int Action { get; set; }
    public bool ShowAdvancedFilters { get; set; }

    //Person Search Variables
    [Display(Name = @"Search")]
    public string SpecialSearch { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = @"Person Id")]
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = @"Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = @"SSN")]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string AddressStatus { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }

    public PersonIncomeViewModel Income { get; set; }
    public List<PersonIncomeListItem> Incomes { get; set; } 



    public PersonLookupViewModel()
    {

        Income = new PersonIncomeViewModel();
        Incomes = new List<PersonIncomeListItem>();

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult _Income(int id)
    {
        var vm = new PersonLookupViewModel();

        var personManager = new dtPerson_v10_r1.Manager( ref mobjSecurity);

        //var person = personManager.GetPersonObject((int)id, vIncludeIncomes: true);
        var person = personManager.GetPersonObject(id, vIncludeIncomes: true);

        var look = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person.Incomes);

        foreach (dtPerson_v10_r1.Income income in person.Incomes)
        {

            if (income.IncomeType_ID == 0)
            {
                var item = new PersonIncomeListItem
                               {
                                   IncomeTypeDesc = "Unknown",
                                   IncomeDesc = income.IncomeDesc,
                                   Income = mobjFormat.FormatObjectToCurrencyString(income.Income)
                               };
                vm.Incomes.Add(item);
            }

            if (income.IncomeType_ID == 1)
            {
                var item = new PersonIncomeListItem
                {
                    IncomeTypeDesc = "Alimony",
                    IncomeDesc = income.IncomeDesc,
                    Income = mobjFormat.FormatObjectToCurrencyString(income.Income)
                };

                vm.Incomes.Add(item);
            }

            if (income.IncomeType_ID == 2)
            {
                var item = new PersonIncomeListItem
                {
                    IncomeTypeDesc = "Child Support",
                    IncomeDesc = income.IncomeDesc,
                    Income = mobjFormat.FormatObjectToCurrencyString(income.Income)
                };

                vm.Incomes.Add(item);
            }

        }

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

View:

```
@using dtDataTools_v10_r1
@using ds_iDMS.Models.Person
@model ds_iDMS.Models.Person.PersonLookupViewModel

@{
    var format = new dtDataTools_v10_r1.CustomFormat();

    var newInitials = (Model.Income.IncomeTypeDesc.First().ToString() + Model.Income.IncomeDesc.First().ToString() + Model.Income.Income.First().ToString()).ToUpper();
}    

    using (Html.DSResponsiveRow(numberOfInputs: ExtensionMethods.NumberOfInputs.TwoInputs))
    {
        using (Html.DSCard(ExtensionMethods.Icon.CustomText, iconInitials: newInitials, color: ExtensionMethods.Colors.PrimaryBlue))
        {
            <div>@Model.Income.IncomeTypeDesc</div>
            <div>@Model.Income.IncomeDesc</div>
            <div>@Model.Income.Income</div>
        }
    }
```

There are some extensions that we have built but they are irrelevant to the issue

The line that errors out is this one:

> var newInitials = (Model.Income.IncomeTypeDesc.First().ToString() + Model.Income.IncomeDesc.First().ToString() + Model.Income.Income.First().ToString()).ToUpper();

Which drives all of the extension methods on the view and as I run the debugger over it all of the parameters read null, however like I said when I run the debugger and check them in the controller they are populated properly.

Sorry about the long post but I wanted to ensure all the detail was there

Comment: don't get what you doing, is `income` not supposed to be `decimal`?

Comment: First I would try to move the code to a normal view - just to check if it is a PartialView related problem. Second I would pass the object via ViewBag/ViewData to check if it is problem how the object is passed or a general problem with the model. Do all Properties in the "Queue.QueueViewModel" have a get/set?

Comment: @maltmann - Yes all of the Queue.QueueViewModel properties have proper get/set's in them.  I will try just passing it via ViewBag to check on that.  However when I check them in the immediate window it is passing but anything is possible :-)

Comment: @jamiedanq - We have conversion extensions because the models are so huge.  So we just pass everything from the model as a string to make it quicker coding and then use extensions to ensure they are formatted correctly.

Comment: @MaximusPrime what is your `View `name?

Comment: The view name is _Income.cshtml

Comment: @MaximusPrime what is the problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to pass the `Object model` to your `Partial View`

```
return PartialView("YourViewName", vm);
```

or using the `Views` path

```
return PartialView("~/YourView.cshtml", vm);
```

**EDIT**

Try starting your Action Method like this

```
    var vm= new Person();
    vm.PersonLookupViewModel = new PersonLookupViewModel();
```

Comment: I tried this jamiedanq and I received the exact same error.

Comment: You need to wrap up you `vm` model in `Person` and pass it

Comment: Because `Person` encapsulates `PersonLookupViewModel` as you are showing on your `View`. If not it will always be `null`

Comment: Hope you know you have to change this bit too `vm.Incomes.Add(item);`

Comment: I don't think that works as when I do that it does not recognize PersonLookupViewModel as part of Person (which it isn't).  PersonLookupViewModel is the View Model that I am passing and Person is the VB object.  I sure appreciate the help however.

Comment: @MaximusPrime that's okay, then edit the answer to show the part that helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I had issues with some of my vb objects and had the vb person take a look at them and she fixed them.

Thank you for all the help

***EDIT***
What had to happen is the vb object had to be re-written and my logic was just fine as it was in the beginning.  I marked the one response to my question as the answer because had it been in true MVC without vb objects attached to it, that would have worked perfectly